# Jetson TX2 GUI not showing up

Tags: lightdm, gui

I have been working on Jetson TX2. I know there is openCV for python2 but I was trying to install opencv 4.0.0 for python3. The build folder was large(>10G) and during the make, it said the disk place is full and killed the progress. 
Then I can't open the file browser. I delete some files to free up some space and Then I reboot it and it goes straight to text mode(bash mode). 
I check the edid and paste it to http://www.edidreader.com/.

```
$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tegradc.0/edid

00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 10 AC 33 D0 53 57 39 30 
25 13 01 03 80 33 1D 78 EE EE 95 A3 54 4C 99 26
0F 50 54 A5 4B 00 71 4F 81 80 D1 C0 01 01 01 01 
01 01 01 01 01 01 02 3A 80 18 71 38 2D 40 58 2C 
45 00 FE 1F 11 00 00 1E 00 00 00 FF 00 44 36 30 
36 52 39 39 41 30 39 57 53 0A 00 00 00 FC 00 44 
45 4C 4C 20 45 32 33 31 30 48 0A 20 00 00 00 FD 
00 32 4C 1E 53 11 00 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 BD
```

Some helpers said it maybe related to full disk space because GUI need some space for temporary files. So I free up 10GB space and rebooted. GUI doesn't show up. Still tty1.

BTW I tried lspci and it gives no output
(just like 
`$lspci  $`nothing shows up).Is it possible I accidentally delete some graphic card driver things? How do I check?

Also when the system is starting(or rebooting) some failure showed up.

`[FAILED]Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
See 'systemctl status dnsmasq.service' for details.
[DEPEND]Dependency failed for Host and Network Name Lookups`

I'll also paste the log file here FYI. [Log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y1nXEn0_41FPBJ8CnMid-L87Y5eNc5jL)

Thank you for your help!